# ASP.NET: How to publish in a folder with commandline

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I want to publish an ASP.NETFramework v4.6.1 project to a local folder.
No zip. No profile.

Just a publication like this:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:MyProject /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:publishDir=".\To\Folder" /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem
```

It compiles well but I get nothing in the destination folder.
I forgot an instruction? The documentation doesnt help me.

Comment: Do you get any error log file in the folder where you are compiling?

Comment: Build succeeded. No errors in log

Comment: The publish output looks like a commercial software release package with the root folder containing a serup.exe file and the release files in subdirectories.  The compile does not do the publish.  See for core : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish  See for Net : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple extra parameters that should get this going. In particular, the publishdir needs to change to OutDir, but the other ones are probably necessary as well.

```
/p:DeployOnbuild=True /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true
/p:OutDir=.\To\Folder /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```